# how to add dashed border on highcharts "area" graph for every point

Tags: svg, highcharts

I have a highcharts "area" graph, and for every point on that graph i want to add a dashed border on the colored area all the way to the bottom.

[image]

Comment: You can add vertical or horizontal grid lines to chart through gridLineWidth properties of xAxis and yAxis, but there isn't any way to draw lines starting from each point by only using highchart api. Only way I can think of is to manually draw them by using svg itself.

Answer (score 3):

To add dashed borders to your area graph, mention the [**`dashstyle`**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.dashStyle) in which each series will be represented in.

### Sample Snippet

```
        Series:[{
            name: 'USA',
            data: [null, null, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104 ],
            dashStyle: 'longdash'
        }]
```

## Possible Values

- Solid
- ShortDash
- ShortDot
- ShortDashDot
- ShortDashDotDot
- Dot
- Dash
- LongDash
- DashDot
- LongDashDot
- LongDashDotDot

### Demo

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/bZYe7/) is here.

Comment: I'm sorry but that was not what i was looking for, I have added an image for better explanation :)