# how can i add in highcharts a different dashStyle just for a part of the graph

Tags: svg, highcharts

At the last two days i want to indicate that i am missing some data, and i'd want it to show a straight dashed line on the same graph. can i change the dashStyle only for parts of the graph?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578648/how-to-add-dashed-border-on-highcharts-area-graph-for-every-point

Comment: Looks like a slightly different question, but it's all part of the same _overall_ problem really.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible, you need two series, first line and second with dashed style.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply 'zones' to a series: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.zones
Just use the dashStyle option like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-dashstyle-dot/

```
 zones: [{
        value: 8
    }, {
        dashStyle: 'dot'
    }]
```